# how to refresh the Div part of my page using javascript after ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am submitting a form using Ajax and storing the data in the database. It is storing the data in the database and without reloading the page it is giving alert box showing that that content has been added.
The same page is showing the content of the database, i need that part to refresh automatically without reloading the page so that it can also fetch the just added information.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();

    }
    if(window.ActiveXobject)
    {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return null;

}
function submitformwithajax()
{
    var myAjaxPostrequest=new GetXmlHttpObject();

    var coursename=document.getElementsByName('cvalue')[0].value;

    var parameter="cvalue="+coursename;

    myAjaxPostrequest.open("POST", "process/do_course.php", true);
    myAjaxPostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myAjaxPostrequest.send(parameter);
    myAjaxPostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(myAjaxPostrequest.readyState==4){
            if(myAjaxPostrequest.status==200){



                if(myAjaxPostrequest.responseText=="true")
                {
                alert("Course Has Been Successfully Added To The Curiculum !");
                 var container = document.getElementById('c');
                var refreshContent = container.innerHTML;
                container.innerHTML = refreshContent;
                }

            }
            else
            document.getElementById("submitcourse").innerHTML="An error has occured making the request";

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

'c' is the ID of the div tag which has to be  reloded.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a higher lever JS library for Ajax? Something like jQuery will make your work a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, the code is to teach students about AJAX

Comment: So you want to reload div`s content (which contains data from db)?

Comment: @Uby var container = document.getElementById('c');
                var refreshContent = container.innerHTML;
                container.innerHTML = refreshContent; should work, but it is not working

Comment: @MiroslavStopka Exactly

Comment: I don't see where 'c' contents is getting updated with the responseText.

Comment: Are you filling that div with Ajax?

Comment: @frabjousB  'c' content contains data from the db, and same page is having form to update that db. so i want after update, without refreshing, 'c' to get updated so that the newly added data is shown there

Comment: You are teaching Ajax and you don't understand it yourself?

Comment: If you want update div content without page reloading, you must send data from server to your browser (use JSON), next you must decode this data and fill your div.

Comment: @MiroslavStopka i am filling the same table which 'c' is using to get data with AJAX

Comment: If you are filling 'c' with course data from DB, it seems you would need to set refreshContent = responseText. You may need to restructure responseText so that there is a responseText.status (would return true or false) and if true, set refreshContent = responseText.courseDetails (or whatever you would like to call it).

Comment: @CaptainPayalytic the code should work, but it is not working, so i am asking for help

Comment: Show us the code - filling table using AJAX

Comment: @TangoTango Teaching students about AJAX can be done with jQuery just as easily as it can be done without. Why not introduce them to a library that they will undoubtedly use in their lifetime as developers?

Comment: @izuriel - AJAX with jQuery, then can you show httprequest? or request states? Im just asking.

Comment: @MiroslavStopka 
<div id="c">
<table border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px">
<tr><td>Sr.No</td><td>Course Name</td></tr>
<?php


$r=$obj->select("select * from bhs_courses");

while($rr=mysql_fetch_row($r))
{
    
    echo "<tr><td>".$rr[0]."</td><td>".$rr[1]."</td></tr>";
    
    
}
?>
</table>

</div>

Comment: @MiroslavStopka jQuery wraps standard AJAX XMLHTTPRequest/ActiveXObject and gives you access to the object direction in the success and error functions which allows you to treat it directly if you really wanted to. In addition to that, it does a lot more for you that prevents you from having to browser sniff or do small conversions like parsing a JSON response (as it will do it for you). I see nothing wrong with teaching jQuery, so long as you explain what jQuery is doing.

Comment: I know that, but im asking if jQuery allows to show how is httprequest created?

Comment: @MiroslavStopka You show how one is created, and used, but teach the practical version of it. Is it really necessary to force them to do it the "old" way?

Comment: @izuriel Someone told something about force? He just want to show them AJAX using Javascript.

Comment: @MiroslavStopka Sorry, I worded that far more hostile than I intended. That was my fault. That being said, you and I are arguing over the details of something that hasn't been given (you may know better than) in detail and I will end it here for that. My only ending statement is that, yes, it's good to understand how to create a request, but actually doing it isn't necessary. I was just recommending using jQuery as they will undoubtedly benefit from that experience.

Comment: @izuriel You have absolute truth about jQuery usability. I dont know much about jQuery because Im using only Javascript. But that will change soon and Im going to learn jQuery because as you said it will do some work for me and save me some time.

Comment: @MiroslavStopka Glad to hear it, I think you'll find it far more enjoyable than using the DOM library and that it will also speed up writing Ajax request. I will also recommend, after using jQuery, checkout out Backbone.js and it's dependant Underscore.js as well.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a bit nonsense:

```
var refreshContent = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML = refreshContent;
```

That way you're not refreshing, the content is exactly the same.

I don't know exactly what do you mean by "DB content", assuming coursename is what you want to add to your DIV then you have to do something like:

```
container.innerHTML += '<p>'+ coursename +'</p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery would benefit your work a lot, your current code via jQuery would look like

```
function submitformwithajax() {
    var coursename = $("[name=cvalue]").val();

    $.post("process/do_course.php", {cvalue: coursename}, function(response) {
        if (response === "true")
        {
            alert("Course Has Been Successfully Added To The Curiculum !");
            var container = $("#c");
            // Not sure why you're setting the container to the container here    
            container.html(container.html());
        }
        else
            $("#submitcourse").text("An error has occured making the request");
    }, "text");
}
```

I don't know why you set the text of the container to the text in the container but that may be an issue you are having. If your server response returns the data that needs to be displayed in th area you can use jQuery (or if you really prefer, the DOM) to update the fields or elements (or add as needed) on the fly. If you need to refresh that section based off a GET request, then just make a GET request for the data in the success statement.

I would also recommend using JSON for the return type from the server instead of plain text. A `{"success": true}` will allow you to check `if (response.success)` instead of using string comparison there.

Also, as a final side note, in Javascript you should **always** prefer `===` over `==` as `===` verifies that value and type both match, the downside to this is that in Javascript `1 == "1"` but `1 === "1"` is not true.

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, should you not persue the jQuery route, you can still implement all of that which I have explained here however you'll have to manually parse the response:

```
var resposne = JSON.parse(myAjaxPostRequest.responseText);
```

From there you can still check `if (response.success)`.

I, personally, recommend showing the students how to do it this long and complex way, and then teaching them how to do it with jQuery. Should any of them pursue a web development career then they will either use jQuery or something very similar in function to it and it's best they learn about these things early on instead of after they get hired. I also suggest JSON returns from the server because it's a more expressive way to return data, instead of just `"true"` (what is true?) you say `{"success": true}` so you can see the request was successful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is going to be return the contents of the "c" element from the ajax call, and then replace the old contents of "c" with the content returned by the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code: You are not filling that table with AJAX. I can only give you this advice. Fill that table dynamically with Javascript.

1. Create function which will find `div#c`.
2. If `div#c` has some children, destroy them.
3. Create a new element table.
4. Fill that table with new rows.

This is how you can make a table dynamically with data from the server which is provided by Ajax. So after sending data from the form you can call this function and your table will be recreated.